# How to remove previous siblings in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove the previous siblings from untop of the `<hr />` tag and next siblings below the `</h2>` tag, The problem is I get this error `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'decompose'`

The HTML that I am trying to parse is something like this

```
<h1>Heading text</h1>

<p style="text-align: justify;">this and everything untop i want to delete</p>
<hr />
<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica;"> this and text below i want to keep</p>

<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica;"> text tex text</p>

<h2>Heading 2</h2>

<p> this and everything below i want to remove</p>
```

Feeding the html like given above doesnt give the result for removing the siblings and only returns the AttributeError. What am I doing wrong and how can i solve this problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for prev_sibling in soup.find("hr").previous_siblings:
    prev_sibling.decompose()

for next_sibling in soup.find("h2").next_siblings:
    prev_sibling.decompose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_previous_siblings`() And `find_next_siblings`()

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<h1>Heading text</h1>
<p style="text-align: justify;">this and everything untop i want to delete</p>
<hr />
<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica;"> this and text below i want to keep</p>
<p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica;"> text tex text</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p> this and everything below i want to remove</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for prev_sibling in soup.find("hr").find_previous_siblings():
    prev_sibling.decompose()

for next_sibling in soup.find("h2").find_next_siblings():
    next_sibling.decompose()

print(soup)
```